# Dependency name inconsistent in google protobuf 2.5.0

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have an web application which I run in windows and linux environment. In linux and *only* linux I'm getting following exception:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid embedded descriptor for "moop_shared.proto".
        at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:301)
        ...

Caused by:
com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$DescriptorValidationException: moop_shared.proto: Dependencies passed to FileDescriptor.buildFrom() don't match those listed in the FileDescriptorProto.
        at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.buildFrom(Descriptors.java:246)
        at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:299)
        ...
```

So I debugged it both locally and remotely comparing the result. I can't understand the following:

**Env:**

protobuf-java-2.5.0

java 7

---

In both cases I run the very same webapp and I'm on the very same place in code which is `com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.java#245` [see code](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.java?r=425)

For the context

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < proto.getDependencyCount(); i++) {
HERE --> if (!dependencies[i].getName().equals(proto.getDependency(i))) {
          throw new DescriptorValidationException(result,
            "Dependencies passed to FileDescriptor.buildFrom() don't match " +
            "those listed in the FileDescriptorProto.");
        }
      }
...
```

And here are the information from debugger:

**Windows:**

```
dependencies[i].getName() = {java.lang.String@3681}"descriptor.proto"
proto.getDependency(i) = {java.lang.String@3682}"descriptor.proto"
dependencies[i].getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() = {java.lang.String@3846}"/C:/Apps/Apache/jakarta/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar"
```

**Linux:**

```
dependencies[i].getName() = {java.lang.String@2444}"google/protobuf/descriptor.proto"
proto.getDependency(i) = {java.lang.String@2445}"descriptor.proto"
dependencies[i].getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() = {java.lang.String@2608}"/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-cnc-webapp-1.6.3-SNAPSHOT.war-_-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar"
```

So both dependecies are loaded from the protobuf jar which is byte indetical (checked) but the result of `dependencies[i].getName()` is different which in the Linux case cause the `DescriptorValidationException`. This is something which is beside my understanding.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this relates to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069295/importing-google-protobuf-descriptor-proto-in-java-protocol-buffers).  It is important that a particular `.proto` file is always imported with exactly the same name.  The compiled classes from `descriptor.proto` are included in the protobuf runtime, and it understands the name to be `google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`.  If you made a copy of `descriptor.proto` and did not put it into a directory called `google/protobuf`, but instead just said `import "descriptor.proto";` in your own file, you will get this error, because the file names don't match.

Comment: You are right as always (at least when it comes to protobuf :). Many thanks for the effort keeping protobuf questions answered!