# Importing "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto" in java protocol buffers

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a `.proto` file definition which needs to import `"google/protobuf/descriptor.proto"` because I use [Custom Options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto?hl=cs).

So in my `.proto` file I do:

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
package ...;

...
```

Since my file didn't compile complaining about the dependency, I got a copy of the descriptor.proto file placing it in the same directory my proto file was.

This solved the problem but I don't believe this is the correct way. Now the `descriptor.proto` gets compiled together with my `.proto` file resulting in having 2 compiled `descriptor.proto` at runtime:

- the one shipped with the `protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar` file
- the one which was compiled together with my `.proto` file

I think the `--proto-path` option should be used somehow but not entirely sure what is the correct way.

Thanks for the best practise tip here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I have used descriptor in a .proto, I have used it like

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

message AddressBook {
  required google.protobuf.FileDescriptorSet proto_files = 1;
```

Then to generate the java (on windows) with addressbookSD.proto in the default directory:

```
protoc addressbookSD.proto --java_out=./ --proto_path=./ --proto_path=<protobuf-install-directory>\src
```

where <**protobuf-install-directory**>  is the protocol buffers install directory.
The key point is descriptor.proto is in

```
<protobuf-install-directory>\src\google\protobuf
```

The levels in an protobuf import stament must match directories in the File system just like they would in java.

So I use <**protobuf-install-directory>\src** as the import directory, The directory structure must be

```
<protobuf-install-directory>\src
    +-- google
         +-- protobuf
             +-- descriptor.proto
```

Comment: Also, on Unix, descriptor.proto is normally installed to `/usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto` or `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`, so add `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` to `--proto_path` on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: I had the same problem recently, and in my case my project depends on `protobuf-lite`. Apparently, protobuf needed the 'full' protobuf for the custom extensions, and therefore I had to add the dependency, as shown here:

```
dependencies {
    protobuf "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"

    ...
}
```

Note that I depend on gRPC in my project, but that works with `com.google.protobuf`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your protoc is not able to find the files in the default include folder for your system

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/694

apt install protobuf-compiler does not put it in include folder

Use this if you are having errors like in linux machines

> google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: File not found.
>
> google/protobuf/duration.proto: File not found.
>
> google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.

For Correct installation on linux systems

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local 'include/*'
rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP
```