# Protobuf message in inner package cannot be imported

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to generate Java code for a proto message that has a reference to another message in a deeper package. When generating the class, `protoc` fails with the following message:

```
"<message_name> is not defined."
```

Where `<message_name>` is the name of the referenced message in the deeper package. For simplicity, I've made the following test directory structure:

```
prototest
  - protos
    - outer.proto
    - inner
      - inner.proto  
  - output
```

Where `inner.proto` is:

```
package protos.inner;

option java_package = "com.package.name.protos.inner";
option java_outer_classname = "InnerProto";

message Inner {
    optional string msg = 1;
}
```

And `outer.proto` is:

```
package protos;

option java_package = "com.package.name.protos";
option java_outer_classname = "OuterProto";

import "protos/inner/inner.proto";

message Outer {
    optional Inner inner = 1;
}
```

Such that the `Outer` message has a reference to the `Inner` message. Doing the reverse seems to work fine (referencing `Outer` from within the `Inner` message), but I've not been able to figure out why the other direction does not work.

The command I'm using to generate `outer.proto` is:

```
protoc \
    --proto_path=$PROTOTEST \
    --java_out=$PROTOTEST/output \
    $PROTOTEST/protos/outer.proto
```

Where `$PROTOTEST` is the absolute path of the prototest directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069295/importing-google-protobuf-descriptor-proto-in-java-protocol-buffers), while the question is different the answer is the same. The protobuf import is not like a Java import but more like  C import / Cobol copy etc. One option is to include the package hierarchy when you use Inner.

Try changing

```
optional Inner inner = 1;
```

to

```
optional protos.inner.Inner inner = 1;
```

---

You are probably aware that you will need to compile both messages

```
protoc --proto_path=$PROTOTEST --java_out=$PROTOTEST/output $PROTOTEST/protos/outer.proto

protoc --proto_path=$PROTOTEST --java_out=$PROTOTEST/output $PROTOTEST/protos/inner/inner.proto
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! This looks like the right solution, I'll give it a try as soon as I get to work tomorrow.